# Exception thrown when attempting to delete object from listview

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working in javafx. I have a Listview which is updated by an ObservableList.
Here is my code.

```
//Dummy list for testing listview
    final ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");


    final ListView<String> listView = new ListView(names.sorted());

    //Try to remove the first element for testing purposes
    listView.getItems().remove(0);
```

When I try to delete I get this exception.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

Is there some step that I'm missing in this case? Or am I trying to use ObservableList and ListView in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList<E>` in an incorrect way.

It's only a wrapper, a view.

To remove an element, you have to use the source collection: `names`.

`javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList<E>` doesn't implements `remove()` but:

> Wraps an ObservableList and sorts it's content. All changes in the
>   ObservableList are propagated immediately to the SortedList. Note:
>   invalid SortedList (as a result of broken comparison) doesn't send any
>   notification to listeners on becoming valid again.

[JavaDoc of javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html)

This [tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) may help.